# How to get raw mouse events in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook app that includes a low-level definition of a chart. It's not an Excel built-in but one I defined following the [WorkBook->Sheets->WorkSheet->ChartObjects->ChartObject->Chart->[Chartarea, Shapes]] chain. I don't want to talk about how long it took to break **that** cipher.

All the drawing stuff works and I'm able to draw lines and place text on the chart.

Now I want to capture mouse events and if they're inside the chart limits, act on them. I've tried everything I can think of including right clicking on the chart and doing the "Assign Macro" bit. The sub is never triggered.

There has to be a place to put a blahblah_onMouseDown(), but I can't find it.

[The current state of the workbook is here](http://smpro.ca/sipmath/SIPshaper1.xlsm)

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to mark this one answered. I haven't got it solved but I've found a source of information I'm reasonably certain will solve it - but I have to reorganize my app to put it to work. There's a lot I didn't realize I didn't know.

[The source is Pearson Software Consulting Here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx)

This web site is loaded with Excel/VBA lore and the quality is way beyond any of the Microsoft documentation.